# How to send a long string in chunks via C sockets without closing the connection?

Tags: c, sockets, c-strings

There are a couple of things that I'm struggling with here.

The first is how to send a string via C stream sockets when you can't guarantee that the string will be sent/received in one go because it's larger than the BUFSIZs or for some other reason.  I imagine that this needs to be done with some sort of infinite loop that you break out of, but I can't figure out how to do this.

The second is I need to do this without breaking the connection.  I know that in a lot of implementations infinite loops are broken by the message sender closing the connection, which results in a recv status of 0.  The recipient can then use this to break out of their loop.  But is there a way of completing the transfer without breaking the connection?

EDIT:  As I understand from the comments, I need to do something like the following, but this produces errors:

```
CLIENT CODE

char message[a_large_number];
snprintf(message, a_large_number, "%s", "a_very_long_string...");
int BUFSIZ = a_small_number;

// establish socket connection

while (1) {
    int sent = send(networkSocket, message, sizeof(message), 0);
    if (sent == (sizeof(message))) {
      break;
    }
  }

// do something else

//close(socket_connection)
```

```
SERVER CODE

int BUFSIZ = another_small_number;
char client_message[];

// establish socket connection

while (1) {
  char buffer[BUFSIZ];
  int received = recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
  if (received == 0) {
      break;
  }
  strcat(client_message, buffer);
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
}


// do something else

// close(socket_connection)
```

Comment: C sockets are too vague. Are we talking about stream sockets? Datagram sockets? If you are talking about TCP stream sockets, assuming by you mentioning "connection", the socket should have no concept of "one go". It's a continuous stream, and you may need to wait and/or poll for more data.

Comment: Just call the send function in a loop?

Comment: So based on your comments, I need to implement something like what I have added to the code section?  There's still something wrong with what I've written though

Comment: Please do not report errors _without_ adding the exact error message or effect. How are we supposed to help you if we don't know the error you see? -- BTW, your send loop tries to send too much and too many times. You need to regard the length of the data, and advance the pointer if you could send a part.

Comment: Your new and updated code have some serious flaws. First of all you resend from the *beginning* each iteration of the loop. You need to keep track of the current position in the loop from where you should send, as well as the remaining size to send. Then on the receiving side you *assume* that the data you receive will be a null-terminated string, which it might be but then it might not. The receiving side also will not process the data until the sender actually closes the connection, which you don't know when it might happen.

Comment: Get the Unix Network Programming book by the late Richard Stevens.